# How to self tab open this using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried more ways. but not working on any method.

```
<span onclick="window.open('index.php?view=watch_video&vt={$ad.vad_token}',"_self")"  class="video-watch pointer">Watch</span>
```

how to open the self tab after the click?

Comment: `"_self"` should be using single-quotes: `'_self'`

Comment: oops working bro. thanks a lot. tried more times.

Comment: (This is what links are for)